# Completion of words on the screen as in VIM (Bash or Tmux)

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

How can I configure Bash, Zsh or Tmux to complete the **last matching identifier on the screen**? Consider this common scenario:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 16, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
From /opt/git/thunder
 * [new branch]      issue540   -> origin/issue547314
   e9204cf..4d42c3f  v2.1       -> origin/v2.1
```

How can I get Bash / Zsh/ Tmux to complete `issue547` on the CLI easily? When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `$ git checkout is` Git helpfully completes to `issue`, but I must complete the digits by myself because **all the previous digits do in fact match existent Git branches**.

In VIM, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for omnicomplete will complete as the previous match, so in this case `issue547314` will in fact be completed. **How can I get this behaviour in Bash, in Zsh or in Tmux**?

I'm currently using Bash 4.2 and Tmux 1.10 on Ubuntu Server (usually 12.04 LTS). I can update to the latest Ubuntu Server LTS (14.04) if needed.

**EDIT**: I would not mind any solution that uses Bash, Zsh, or Tmux as long as it is not difficult to use. So <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or some other such shortcut would be fine, but not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>א</kbd>.

Comment: Pretty sure this would take a fairly large revision of the bash source.

Comment: @Kevin: I figured as much, but hopefully either the amazing zsh can handle it, or perhaps tmux.

Comment: [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/kittens/hints/) (the terminal emulator) supports something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that feature that OP is looking for is called [dabbrev-expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html) in Emacs world:

> Expand the word in the buffer before point as a dynamic abbrev, by
>   searching in the buffer for words starting with that abbreviation
>   (v-expand).

`xterm` also has `dabbrev-expand` feature but it's a bit less smart than Emacs counterpart but it's *very* useful to me and one was one of the reasons for which I switched to `xterm`. Inside `xterm` window one can use a custom keybinding specified in `~/.Xresources` to invoke `dabbrev-expand` on a given string. For example, I have the following entry in my `~/.Xresources` (I use `uxterm`, an Unicode version of xterm):

```
UXTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \n\
     Meta <Key>/:dabbrev-expand() \n\
```

Inside `xterm` window I can use `M-/` (`ALT + /`) to invoke `dabbrev-expand`. `xterm` will look for all strings visible on the screen that start with letters I typed. Example:

```
$ echo a_very_long_string bye by
$ a_v
```

If I pressed `M-/` now `xterm` would expand `a_v` to `a_very_long_string`. Unfortunately, as I said `xterm` is not so smart and its `dabbrev-expand` feature will only work on full strings. So, in your case `is` would be expanded to `issue540` and not `issue547314` because `issue547314` is a part of `origin/issue547314` (think about it as `\b` in regular expressions, it's a bit similar although most regular expressions engines would catch both occurrences of `issue` strings in `\bissue.+\b`). **But**, you can type `or` and then pres `M-/`. `xterm` will first expand `or` to `origin/v2.1`, this is not what we want so press `M-/` again and `xterm` will expand it to `origin/issue547314`. Now, if you use Bash you can do `M-b`, `C-w` and `C-e` to remove `origin/` part. To sum up, `dabbrev-expand` inside `xterm` is not as good as in Emacs (and Vim I guess) but it's still faster than rewriting long strings by hand and less typo-prone. And in most cases it will expand directly to the desired string without need to remove redundant parts. You just need to get used to it - look at string you want to have at cursor and see if it's not preceded by something else, and if it is type a preceding part and remove it after expansion.

Note that `xterm` is not compiled with `dabbrev-expand` feature by default and you have to enable it explicitly. However, version of `xterm` in Ubuntu repositories is compiled with `dabbrev-expand` and you can use it right away.

Comment: Thank you Arkadiusz, this seems to be close enough to what I need. Note that I cannot get it to work! Perhaps my `xterm` and `uxterm` are not compiled for dabbrev-expand, I could find no mention of the feature in `-help`. How can I see the compile flags (like with `vim --version`)? Note that I also tried the config line in `~/.Xresources` as `Meta <KeyPress> /: dabbrev-expand() \n\ ` as found [here](https://snarfed.org/dotfiles/.Xresources) but that did not help, either.

Comment: It may be your xterm has been compiled without dabbrev-expand. How did you install xterm? After modifying ~/.Xresources do `xrdb -merge .Xresources` in xterm.

Comment: That most certainly did it, Arkadiusz! Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to give the question a few more hours until the bounty period ends, but I'm pretty sure that you are a shoe-in. The only problem is the requirement for xterm, which is terrible! But now that I know the proper name for the feature I can google it for [other applications](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg01278.html). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Arkadiusz! Though I won't be using the xterm solution, you have certainly pointed me in the right direction. Apparantly `zsh` does have this facility.

Comment: xterm can be made not so terrible, including antialiased fonts: http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2013/07/hidden-gems-of-xterm.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with [extrakto](https://github.com/laktak/extrakto):

- press tmux `prefix + tab` to start extrakto
- fuzzy find the text/path/url
- press

  - `tab` to insert it to the current pane,
  - `enter` to copy it to the clipboard,
  - `ctrl-o` to open the path/url or
  - `ctrl-e` to edit with `$EDITOR`

Answer (score 0):

Bash as a similar facility called bash completetion. You can make use of it by hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key when providing arguments to commands when you're typing them.

#### Example

If I start by typing `ls` and then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice you'll get Bash to provide a list of matching files (and command line switches) to whatever command you're attempting to use:

```
$ ls <---- hit Tab x 2
Display all 232 possibilities? (y or n)
```

And here's the example with switches:

```
$ ls -- <---- hit Tab x 2
--all                 --format=                                  --quote-name
--almost-all          --group-directories-first
....
....
```

#### Setup?

My installation already included a rule for `git`:

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

The installation of this file was done when I installed the `git` package. I'm on Fedora 19, but other distros should be doing this as well.

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/bash_completion.d/git
git-1.8.3.1-1.fc19.x86_64
```

Looking at the rules file it explains that it will facilitate auto-completion in the following situations:

```
# The contained completion routines provide support for completing:
#
#    *) local and remote branch names
#    *) local and remote tag names
#    *) .git/remotes file names
#    *) git 'subcommands'
#    *) tree paths within 'ref:path/to/file' expressions
#    *) file paths within current working directory and index
#    *) common --long-options
#
```

So this should "just work" for you.

Comment: Bash completion and Git completion work (as I mention in the OP). The change that I would like to perform is to have it complete on the first Tab press the last legal value shown on the screen. This is how VIM Omnicompletion works.

Comment: @dotancohen - I don't see now that would be possible beyond what I've described.