# How can I use the output of a command without using the mouse?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, gnu-screen

Imagine you issued a `find` command and now you want to use one line of the resulting output as an argument.

```
$ find ..
fileA
fileB
$ vi <CURSOR>   # now do what to achive:
$ vi fileB
```

**Current workaround:**
Double click on *fileB* (selection is extended automatically) and press middle mouse button (paste on X). Works but uses the mouse.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Tab completion — Works in most shells but only for files.
2. Hook the shell — Like [scm_breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze); This is pretty much what I seek, but it's limited to git.
3. Use `screen` — Pretty close, but still many key strokes. And it needs `screen`....
4. store output in bash variable (GMaster) — That would only work if the find command outputs one line. How do I access the second line like in the example?
5. pipe command to editor (jasonwryan) — Works but executes the command twice. That may be time consuming or not even possible.
6. use emacs Dynamic Abbrev Expansion (Arkadiusz Drabczyk, Michael Vehrs) — Thats what I am looking for but I would not like to start with emacs.

**Solution for me:**
"Dynamic Abbrev Expansion". Now I have the name of this feature I was looking for. I will start a new question about how to get his "dabbrev-expand" in other software's:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281298/list-of-sofwares-inspired-by-emacs-dabbrev-expand.

**Vision of the best solution for me:**
Something like the hint mode from *vimperator* or *easymotion* in Vim, to yank text from the output of the current terminal.

Comment: Maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable

Comment: Arrow up to retrieve the command from history (or `Ctrl-r` if it is not the last), `v` to edit the command and pipe the (grepped, if necessary) output to $EDITOR...

Comment: I'd have to agree with @jasonwryan on this one.  The major *advantage* to building up a long pipeline that does *exactly* what you want, instead of doing the bits and pieces of what you want interactively, is that it's reusable.  The whole long command line can be dumped into a script as-is and will do exactly what you want it to do, as many times as you want to use it.

Comment: A rule you will learn if you work with computers professionally is: There's no task you will perform *only once, ever*.

Comment: @Wildcard The question is not  about automation or scripting instead about working daily in terminals (in fact as a professional ;-) ). An now an then you just need one word, words or line copied from the current output. Maybe I should clarify my question in that direction. How would you name the text visible in the terminal?

Comment: @Tristan, no, it's a perfectly good question.  I upvoted it and I'd be interested in the answer.  But most of the time, the best action to take is to simply modify the previous command by appending a pipe `|` and another command to parse the output.  You could do that with e.g. `!! | someothercommand`

Comment: (To answer your terminology question, it's called the "scrollback buffer.")

Comment: You're looking for `dabbrev-expand`.  It's a feature that many
terminal emulators such as `xterm` have, I described it in this
answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139016/72304.  I use this
feature on a daily basis, I can't imagine living without it.

Comment: If the _find_ parameters were made to be more specific, there'd be no need for mousing, history, etc.  Something like `find revised_foo | xargs vi` would just work.

Comment: If you have specific issues with `screen`, there's also `tmux`.

Comment: If you're using `vi` mode for your editing, up arrow to the previous command then `v` to drop the command into the editor. Next, `!!bash` to re-execute the command and replace it with its output ready for editing.

Comment: I sense this could be a XYProblem: if your goal is to delete some file with a very weird name, you can  :  `ls -li`  # to see the files inodes numbers as well (for exemple: you may find out that your weirdly named file has inode #nnnnn) and then `find /path/to/directory/ -inum 'nnnnn' -exec rm '{}' ';'` to delete it, whatever its name is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `emacs`, start an inferior shell and issue your command. The output will be available in the shell buffer and can be selected using the usual commands. Alternatively,

```
select file in $(find <whatever>); do vi $file; break; done
```

The `emacs` approach is more practical if you already know the editor. `Emacs` can run arbitrary "inferior processes", ie. interactive commands with their input and output connected to an emacs buffer. So, `M-x shell-mode` starts an inferior shell, you type your `find` command and the output of that command is available in the buffer

```
$ find .. -name "*.sh"
../self.sh
../scheme/random.sh
../scheme/sample.sh
```

Now, you move you cursor to the file you are interested in and type `M-x find-file-at-point` to edit that file in a different buffer.

Comment: The emacs sounds promising. Would you mind to eloberate?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind re-running the command from which you need the output, then add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
# Load completion menu feature.
zmodload zsh/complist

# `fc -e :` re-runs the last history entry.
# ${(f)…} splits the string on newlines.
copy-output() compadd ${(f)"$( fc -e : 2> /dev/null )"}

# Create a completion menu widget & bind it.
zle -C copy-output menu-select copy-output 
bindkey '^[!' copy-output
```

Now you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> to rerun the previous command and get a menu from which you can select what to insert in the new command line.

So, for your example:

```bsh
% find ..
fileA
fileB
% vi <ALT-!>
fileA  fileB
```

The output is shown underneath the command line and you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the arrow keys to select the one you want. To select more than one, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Things like this make me consider ditching bash :) can you elaborate on what this means: `${(f)"$( fc -e : 2> /dev/null )"}` - in as much detail as you can, or at least what is `fc -e` and `(f)` ?

Comment: I’ve now added some code comments. Hopefully it’s clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Zsh plugin created to do specifically what you request: https://github.com/psprint/ztrace

Comment: Ztrace seems to be designed to be explicitly invoked before running a few commands, not to be always running in your shell.