# How can I navigate and copy some text from the past terminal output?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

#### Problem

Very often when I work with `git` I need to copy some content from the output of the last command. And I hate switching from keyboard to trackpad/mouse.

**Case #1**

```
...
➜  extract_ttc git:(feature/simplify-gha-workflows) git push
fatal: The current branch feature/simplify-gha-workflows has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature/simplify-gha-workflows
```

I need to copy `git push --set-upstream origin feature/simplify-gha-workflows` manually to execute, so I switching to mouse/trackpad from keyboard

**Case #2**

```
...
➜  extract_ttc git:(feature/simplify-gha-workflows) git push --set-upstream origin feature/simplify-gha-workflows
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.16 KiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'feature/simplify-gha-workflows' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/fontist/extract_ttc/pull/new/feature/simplify-gha-workflows
remote:
To github.com:fontist/extract_ttc.git
 * [new branch]      feature/simplify-gha-workflows -> feature/simplify-gha-workflows
Branch 'feature/simplify-gha-workflows' set up to track remote branch 'feature/simplify-gha-workflows' from 'origin'.
```

I need to copy `https://github.com/fontist/extract_ttc/pull/new/feature/simplify-gha-workflows` again to execute `open`

#### Questions

- Is there a way to navigate the terminal output of the past commands (without mouse/trackpad)?
- Is there some approach that doesn't depend on the terminal app (for example I use iTerm on OSX)?
- If there is no solution in the way how I imagined it: what are possible approaches to achieve the same with keyboard only?

Comment: Use a multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` - they support scrolling, highlighting and copying from the terminal buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I hate switching from keyboard to trackpad/mouse.

Yeah, me too.

> Is there a way to navigate the terminal output of the past commands (without mouse/trackpad)?

Yes, use [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen) or
[tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki). In GNU screen for example
you need to press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> to
enter copy mode and navigate around the terminal using j/k/h/l
keys. You can also copy some text and paste in another GNU screen
window or add something like that to ~/.screenrc to copy selected text
to X clipboard (although X is not used any more on macOS AFAIK):

```
bind b eval writebuf 'exec /bin/sh -c " xsel -i < /tmp/screen-exchange"' 'exec /bin/sh -c "killall xsel"'
```

> Is there some approach that doesn't depend on the terminal app (for example I use iTerm on OSX)?

GNU screen and tmux do not depend on the terminal emulator.

> If there is no solution in the way how I imagined it: what are possible approaches to achieve the same with keyboard only?

*dabbrev-expand* in xterm as described at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139016/72304. That would do *exactly* what you want. I don't know if a similar feature is available in iTerm.

Answer (score 1):

[Wez's Terminal](https://github.com/wez/wezterm), a *GPU-accelerated cross-platform terminal emulator and multiplexer written by [@wez](https://github.com/wez) and implemented in [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)*, has a special [Quick Select Mode](https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/quickselect.html) for this

> Quick Select mode allows you to quickly highlight text that matches commonly copied patterns, select a match by typing a one-or-two character prefix and copy it to the clipboard.
>
> The `QuickSelect` key assignment is used to enter quick select mode; it is bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> by default.

[image: WezTerm quick select mode demo]